# Are there any proved consistent quantum continuous cellular automata/game of life model?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, continuum-mechanics, discrete, cellular-automaton

There are quantum cellular automata (continuous game of life, which is a type of cellular automata): https://hal.archives-ouvertes.fr/hal-00542373/document

There are continuous cellular automata (continuous game of life which is a type of cellular automata) https://arxiv.org/abs/1111.1567

But I have not seen any quantum continuous cellular automata.

I found a paper (https://arxiv.org/abs/1701.02252) that says that with a Hamiltonian cellular automaton there can be a map between cellular automaton and quantum continuous, but a user in this site, told me that it was not really continuous because time was discrete even in a continuous universe in that model

I also found this paper: https://arxiv.org/abs/1606.08764

There, it is said "We realize constant-space quantum computation by measure-many two-way quantum finite automata"
I don't know if that means that this model is a quantum continuous (in space, time...etc) cellular automata/game of life

So do you know of any model that would satisfy what I ask?

Comment: I don’t think this is quite the right question to ask. If you define a cellular automaton as anything with discrete time and discrete space and fixed update rules, then obviously _anything_ can be written as a cellular automaton. This is kind of like how almost every numerical simulation ever works. It’s just like how you could write any program in assembly if you really wanted to.

Comment: However, the fact that you can write physical laws in terms of cellular automata doesn’t mean you should. It seems to be an extremely clunky and inefficient rewriting of something we already know.

Comment: @knzhou why is it clunky and inefficient?

Comment: @knzhou except there are provably numbers we can't compute, so it's not *obvious* to me that anything can be written that way?

Comment: @CDCM No, that's a mathematician's way of viewing things. Such numbers don't matter for physics. For the purposes of physics you could even postulate that all numbers are multiples of $10^{-100}$. Nothing will go wrong, because we cannot measure nearly that precisely anyway.

Comment: @CDCM As I said above, this kind of ultra-finitism is clunky and inefficient; you _want_ the real line to, e.g. write down calculus. But you don't _need_ it to describe observation.

Comment: @CDCM but could there be advanced brain-like cellular automata that could compute these numbers? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brian%27s_Brain

Comment: @knzhou what do you mean with "you don't need it to describe observation"? I still not fully understand why is it clunky/inefficient. PS: if you are going to ignore me, please, next time don't say anything, because now I have one more doubt that is not solved and I'll have to find someone else to solve it, wasting more and more time, since you don't answer my questions. I don't understand why you participated in this discussion if you don't want to follow it.